# Wrong state class error after updating FB audience-network-sdk:6.11.0

Tags: android, viewstate, facebook-audience-network

After updating FAN from `'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.5.0'` to `'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.11.0'` got following crash. I have already checked in my hierarchy there is no same id exist and still got this crash

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state
> class, expecting View State but received class
> com.facebook.ads.internal.util.parcelable.WrappedParcelable instead.
> This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id
> in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/0x3. Make sure other views
> do not use the same id.
> at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:21256)
> at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:21228)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4118)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:4124)
> at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:21206)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:689)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:3151)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:3142)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:579)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:264)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1881)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1814)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:538)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8227)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:589)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1071)

Comment: @badoualy No, Working on it

Comment: Do you have a solution for this problem? Please share

Answer (score 0):

Disabling state save/restoration seems to do the trick:

```
view.isSaveEnabled = false
view.isSaveFromParentEnabled = false
```

Comment: where should I place this

Answer (score 0):

My application encountered this error.

If your application does not need to restore data when activity recreates.

Let's do this in Activity and Fragment

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
     savedInstanceState.clear()
 }
```